# mouseIsPressed combined mouseMoved() not work

Tags: p5.js

I want to make a doodling application, drawing strokes when mouse is moving, in the mousemove event handler, below code works:

```
line(lastX, lastY, mouseX, mouseY);
lastX = mouseX;
lastY = mouseY;
```

However, when I wrap the codes into an if statement like:

```
if (mouseIsPressed) {
...
}
```

Nothing, if I move the codes into draw function and set that condition, it works. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [mouseMoved()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseMoved) reference:

> The mouseMoved() function is called every time the mouse moves and a mouse button is not pressed.

So the `mouseMoved()` function won't be called if you are pressing a mouse button. If you put some code into an if block like:

```
if (mouseIsPressed) {
...
}
```

and put that block into `mouseMoved()`, then that code will never be executed.

It's totally ok to put that if block directly in the `draw()` function. You don't have to use `mouseMoved()` in this case :)